Spring Batch : async with AsyncItemProcessor and AsyncItemWriter
I want to improve my spring batch performance with async processing
I have noticed the class AsyncItemProcessor has a method setTaskExecutor :
public AsyncItemProcessor asyncDataProcessor() throws Exception {
    AsyncItemProcessor<List<Data>, List<Data>> processor = new AsyncItemProcessor<>();
    processor.setDelegate(dataProcessor());
    processor.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor());
    return processor;
}

But StepBuilder class also has this taskExecutor method :
@Bean
public Step dataStep(JobRepository jobRepository,
                       PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager, DataService dataService) throws Exception {
    return new StepBuilder("dataStep", jobRepository)
            .<List<Data>, List<Data>>chunk(1, transactionManager)
            .reader(dataItemReader(dataService))
            .processor(asyncDataProcessor())
            .writer(asyncDataWriter(dataService))
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .build();
}

Should I use this methods in both beans definitions ? What's the difference between the setTaskExecutor  in AsyncItemProcessor and taskExecutor in StepBuilder ?

When you set a task executor on the step builder, you configure a multi-threaded step where chunks are processed concurrently by multiple threads (ie each chunk will be read/processed/written by a different thread). This is explained in the Multi-threaded Step section.
With the AsyncItemProcessor/AsyncItemWriter approach, only the item processor is executed concurrently. See Asynchronous Processors

OK thanks so AsyncItemWriter is async because it works in "fire and forget" mode, but without multi threads, correct ?

The async approach will also use multiple threads from the task executor, but will only process items concurrently (ie only the item processor is concurrent). The async writer will just unwrap the results coming from the async processor and write them when ready.
